# How can I get shell_exec to run on my server?

Tags: python, php, shell-exec

So I know there are plenty of similar questions on the site, but I can't find any answers that explain clearly enough a solution to my problem. Hopefully a clear answers to this could help many others!

I've got two files, test.php and test.py.

**test.php**

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec('test.py');
  echo $output;
?>
```

**test.py**

```
print("hello, world")
```

PHP prints "hello, world" on localhost, but not on the server (Unix, I think), where everything is blank. I can successfully run test.py on the server with the command line, and have checked function_exists('shell_exec') in PHP, which it does.

I understand that I might need to give the server permission to use shell_exec, but this is where I get a bit confused. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: enable error reporting, only that will tell you why, also you may need tell it its a python script as your missing the hashbang `shell_exec('python test.py')`, also it should be executable

Comment: Hi Lawrence, Thanks so much for responding. Good suggestions but sadly neither has solved it. I've tried the hashbang python (and python3) but no luck. I've also used

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

to try and find errors but it's not finding any (I did check it worked with another a deliberate error).

Would really appreciate any other ideas you/anyone might have? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally solved this. Turns out

$output = exec('python test.py');

does the job. Thanks to Lawrence for the pointer!